# How to check Jboss server is secured or non-secured via JNDI

Tags: ssl, jboss7.x, jndi

I have a problem while connecting to JBoss 7 server via JNDI. I want to check whether Jboss 7 is secured or non-secured so that I can add the proper parameters while connecting to it.

If Jboss server is secured, I need to add SSL parameters to open secured connection.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just try it one way, catch the exception, then try it the other way. But why don't you know in advance?

Comment: Yes, I already tried your way, but I want to find a better solution. In my project SSL on Jboss is dynamic, it can be enabled/disabled by any users.

Comment: Define 'better'. What makes you think a better solution even exists?